# AppenChild only once - Check if exists

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a login form, based on Javascript. I want to create the text boxes for the login dynamically when they are needed, so I'm using appendchild. However, by default appendchild just adds the element over and over again. What is a good practice on how to check if the element already exists, so that it does not add it anymore?

What I have so far:

```
function checktest(){
    var emailfieldcheck = document.getElementById("emailfield");
    var pwfieldcheck = document.getElementById("passwordfield");

   if (emailfieldcheck == null){

    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "email");
    x.setAttribute("id", "emailfield");
    y.setAttribute("type", "password");
    y.setAttribute("id", "passwordfield");

    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(y);

    }
    else{
      handleSignUp(); //Textboxes exist, now do the login
    };
}
```

This doesn't seem to do the job, since I think *(emailfieldcheck == null)* is not the proper way to check if it exists.

Comment: That is indeed the correct way to check if an element exist ?

Comment: @adeneo The issue right now is that it triggers `handleSignUp();` in the _else_ already the first time this function is called. `handleSignUp();` then yells that it's missing data. However, it also adds the fields (only once, that works), but triggers the signup at the same time.

Comment: @FelixF. remove `else` section and directly put `handleSignUp();` in place of it

Comment: It's either going in the `if` part or the `else` part, it can't do both, unless you've done something that calls the function twice. Add some console.logs and see what's going on

Comment: @gurvinder372 Then there wouldn't be time for the User to enter the data, which the signup function needs, right?

Comment: @FelixF. why would generating a form and handling sign-up be done on a same event/function?

Comment: Never mind, it works now. There was another eventlistener in the signup function, which triggered too early.